# Conditional HTML form based on the beginning letter in a Text Field

Tags: javascript, html, string, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm making an HTML form where the user submits a user ID, and based on the first letter of that ID, it will redirect to specific page of a website.

The website is a WordPress site, and every time I test it, instead of going to my placeholders links (Youtube & Reddit), it goes to a blank WP page based off the inputted ID.

Eg. Submitting "A123" directs to website.com/?participantID=A123 instead of Reddit (placeholder site).

This could be a WP issue, but feel like I'm not turning the input into a string correctly. Honestly, I'm not that confident with any of the JS I've written Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
<form onsubmit="pageRedirect()">
  
<input type="text" id="participantID" name="participantID">
<input type="submit">
</form>

<script>
  let inputValue = document.getElementById("participantID");

pageRedirect() {

if ("inputValue".startsWith("A")) {
action="https://reddit.com";
}
else {
    action="https://youtube.com";
  }
}
  </script>
```

Comment: why the quotes around `"inputValue"` in `"inputValue".startsWith("A")`? - it is a variable...

Comment: Okay, that makes sense! Honestly, I'm not sure why I put inputValue in quotes. It's been a long day lol

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be assigning the URL to an action variable, but otherwise doing nothing. Therefore the form does it default action of POSTing to the current page. Your accessing of the input value is also incorrect.

*You also seem to be missing the `function` keyword for your `pageRedirect()` function?*

You can cancel this default behavior by returning false, and do whatever you want instead:

```js
function pageRedirect() {
    const inputValue = document.getElementById('participantID').value;
    if (inputValue.startsWith('A')) {
        document.location.href = "https://reddit.com";
    } else {
        document.location.href = "https://youtube.com";
    }
    // Returning false in `onsubmit` cancels the form
    return false;
}
```

Of course, this is a simple (HTTP GET) "redirect" to those sites. If you want to actually POST the data, that's another story.

Comment: Thanks! It seems to be ignoring return false, but I'm going to play around with it some more tmrw. I'm off the clock now!

Comment: Ah, it seems I forgot to mention that your `onsubmit` should look like `onsubmit="return pageRedirect()"`. One of those weird quirks JS in the browser has.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested it though but this should work.

I can modify my answer if you require

```
<form id="redirectForm">
  <input type="text" id="participantID" name="participantID" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>

<script>  
 document.getElementById("redirectForm").addEventListener("submit",function (event) {
event.preventDefault()
        let inputValue = document.getElementById("participantID").value;
    
        if (inputValue.startsWith("A")) {
          window.location = "https://reddit.com";
        } else {
          window.location = "https://youtube.com";
        }
        return false;
      })
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks! I've played around with yours and Kelvin's revisions, but it seems to be ignoring the return false. But, I'm done for the day, so I'll play around more tmrw.

Answer (score 0):

Having looked at the question again just now I believe I now understand the requirement and can point you in the right direction. Alas a `snippet` here will not actually run the `redirect` but the following appears to do what you need.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title></title>
        <script>
        
            const buildurl=function( endpoint, params ){
                let url=new URL( endpoint );
                url.search = new URLSearchParams( params ).toString();
                return url;
            };

            const pageRedirect=function(e){
                // prevent the form doing what it should
                e.preventDefault();
                // find reference to the form from the event target
                let form=e.target;
                // find the input element
                let input=form.querySelector('input[ name="participantID" ]');
                // prepare the payload to send to 3rd party site
                let args={};
                    args[ input.name ]=input.value;
                    
                // determine which site to redirect to
                let endpoint=input.value.startsWith('A') ? 'https://reddit.com' : 'https://youtube.com';

                // construct the target url and set form attributes
                form.action=buildurl( endpoint, args );
                form.target='_blank';
                
                // submit the form
                return form.submit();
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form onsubmit='return pageRedirect(event)'>
          <input type='text' name='participantID' />
          <input type='submit' />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```